# Using super() in Python, I do not understand this last __init__ call

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes as follows:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, Obj_a, Obj_b):
        super().__init__(Obj_a, Obj_b)

class Report(object):
    def __init__(self, Obj_a, Obj_b):
        super().__init__()

class ReportingPage(Page,Report):
    def __init__(self, Obj_a, Obj_b):
        super().__init__(Obj_a, Obj_b)
```

I instantiate a `ReportingPage` object. To do this Python crawls up the MRO:

1. The `Page` object is called first, as it's ordered first in the inheritance list for `ReportingPage`, where it calls its own `__init__` method.
2. Then it does the same for `Report`.

Two things I don't understand:

1. Why I *must* pass in arguments to the `super.__init__` in `Page`, when `Page` is just going to call `__init__` on what it inherits from, `object`.
2. Why I don't have to do the same thing for `Report`.

Comment: This should throw a `TypeError` when you try to make a `Page` instance, because `object.__init__` takes no arguments

Comment: 1. Because `Page.__init__` is going to call `Report.__init__` when invoked via `ReportingPage.__init__`; that's next in the MRO. 2. Because it's the last one to get called before `object.__init__`, there's nothing for it to pass them on to (indeed it *mustn't* pass any, as `object.__init__` doesn't accept them).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It doesnt throw a TypeError when instantiating a ReportingPage.

Comment: @DrewAckerman they said *"when you try to make a `Page` instance"*, i.e. instantiating `Page(1, 2)` directly. Your classes do not correctly support multiple inheritance, and only work when instantiating a `ReportingPage` or `Report`.

Comment: Related: [super-harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).  You have created a diamond inheritance in `ReportingPage` and so you're somewhat obliged to pass *args, **kwargs in `__init__`.

Comment: @johnsharpe Alright, so when we are talking about super, super isnt concerned with the subclasses super class, its concerned with the next class in the MRO? This is my first time trying to implement multiple inheritance vs multi-level inheritance.

Comment: @wim: now read [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) too.

Comment: @wim Diamond Inheritance, the very thing i wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`super()` looks at the MRO of the *current instance*. It doesn't matter here that the current *class* inherits only from `object`.

The MRO of `ReportingPage` puts `Report` between `Page` and `object`:

```
>>> ReportingPage.__mro__
(<class '__main__.ReportingPage'>, <class '__main__.Page'>, <class '__main__.Report'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So when you call `super()` in `Page.__init__()`, the next class in the MRO is `Report`, and you end up calling the `Report.__init__` method.

You need to make your classes more cooperative; you could use keyword arguments and a catch-all `**kwargs` argument to do so:

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, pagenum, **kwargs):
        self.pagenum = pagenum
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Report(object):
    def __init__(self, title, **kwargs):
        self.title = title
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class ReportingPage(Page, Report):
    def __init__(self, footer=None, **kwargs):
        self.footer = footer
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Each method passes along the remaining keyword arguments here, to the next `__init__` in the MRO, and in the end you'll have an empty dictionary to pass to `object.__init__()`. If you add in a `print(kwargs)` wrapper to each `__init__` method, you can see that `kwargs` becomes smaller as fewer values are passed on to the next call.

```
>>> def print_wrapper(name, f):
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...         print(name, '->', kwargs)
...         return f(*args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> for cls in ReportingPage.__mro__[:-1]:  # all except object
...     cls.__init__ = print_wrapper(cls.__name__, cls.__init__)
...
>>> ReportingPage(title='Watching Paint Dry II: The Second Coat', pagenum=42)
ReportingPage -> {'title': 'Watching Paint Dry II: The Second Coat', 'pagenum': 42}
Page -> {'title': 'Watching Paint Dry II: The Second Coat', 'pagenum': 42}
Report -> {'title': 'Watching Paint Dry II: The Second Coat'}
<__main__.ReportingPage object at 0x109e3c1d0>
```

Only `title` remains, which `Report.__init__()` consumes, so an empty `kwargs` dictionary is passed to `object.__init__()`

You may be interested in [Raymond Hettinger's *super considered super*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), including his [PyCon 2015 presentation](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Asking the question here and seeing that it calls based off of MRO ordering and not subclass/superclass ordering finally made this all click. This..Is messy.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters. Is the only solution to explicitly call the __init__ of both classes in this "subclasses" __init__?

Comment: @DrewAckerman: no, I added the cooperative approach to my answer.

Comment: @DrewAckerman: `super()` is designed to make cooperative multiple inheritance clear and consistent. But if you are not designing cooperative clases, then don't use `super()` and call the methods directly on the parent class.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters What designates a class as co-operative? Just so that I know if this is a proper use case

Comment: @DrewAckerman: the handling of additional arguments with `**kwargs` (and perhaps `*args`).